# How do you monitor an external domain trust?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, splunk, trust-relationship

We have multiple external domain trusts with different companies, and while I know how to validate the trust in "Windows Domains and Trusts", I am wondering if anyone knows how to monitor it with a script or log in real time?

We use Splunk and would like to report on this and send alerts if the trust goes down.

I know there is a WMIObject that can be checked to return "TrustStatus OK" or "False". The problem with that is it seems inconsistent, and not real time.

We have a lab environment where we can turn off the only DC in the trusted site or cut the network connection and the WMIObject will not update for 3 or 4 minutes. I also don't want to use wmi in general.

If anyone has monitoring in place for this how did you do it? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.